# Реклама в профиле не оставляющего сообщений пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, страница-учётной-записи, реклама

[Профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209417/ajt-ru-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B?tab=profile). Участник зарегистрировался на множестве проектов Stack Exchange, не оставляя при этом нигде сообщений. По всей видимости, исключительно с целью продвижения не относящегося к программированию и, возможно, [мошеннического](http://www.info-forum.ru/topic/30854-moshenniki-ajtru/) сайта в поисковых системах.

Куда писать о подобных случаях? На страницах профиля не нашёл какого-либо аналога кнопки «Тревога».

**UPD**

Локально в русском Stack Overflow, вижу, его уже заблокировали, но реклама в профиле осталась на 37 сайтах сети.

Answer (score 7):

На данный момент у профиля 6 просмотров, из которых 3 принадлежат вам, мне и @KromStern. Чтобы получить посещение сайта, нужно, чтобы случайный посетитель СО каким-то немыслимым способом нашёл этот пустой профиль, прочитал маловменяемый текст, умудрился его осмыслить, вдохновился описанием, нашёл ссылку в текстовом виде в заголовке, скопировал в буфер обмена, открыл новую вкладку, вставил адрес и нажал на кнопку перехода.

Положим, что вероятность каждого события где-то в районе 10%, что запредельно щедро. После перемножения вероятностей со всей Земли набирается полтора землекопа.

Стоит ли заморачиваться?

P. S. Стандартная процедура при необходимости пожаловаться модераторам на то, жалобы на что движок не подерживает — это найти первый попавшийся пост и прицепить жалобу к нему с припиской "жалоба не на этот пост". Впрочем, проще написать в чат.

Comment: Discord, я смотрел [robots.txt](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) русскоязычного Stack Overflow — страницы профилей пользователей туда не занесены. Если так, то эта реклама проиндексируется краулерами, и на неё можно будет попасть из поисковиков. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, по какому запросу например? :)

Comment: @Grundy,  `ajt.ru отзывы`.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Тот, кто будет делать этот запрос, заведомо не попадётся на мошенничество.

Comment: @Discord, а что, если это мульт Саши и он так раскручивает свой сайт?!!! :-D

Comment: @Grundy Тогда он слишком аккуратно избегает создания прямой ссылки на сайт.

Comment: @Discord, возможно у него какой-то хитрый план?

Comment: Discord, Ваш профиль [проиндексирован](https://www.google.ru/search?q=discord+site:ru.stackoverflow.com), значит, видимо, то же самое вскоре произойдёт и с профилем того пользователя. Нельзя пускать на самотёк, ибо Stack Overflow может стать удобной площадкой для спамеров.

Comment: @Grundy, не знаю, чем вызвал подозрение, но если что, против проверок меня на наличие дополнительных аккаунтов не возражаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Первого удалил Nicolas. Вот ещё один был, его я удалил. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204778/unixdoc-ru?tab=profile