# Учётки-организации это норма?

Tags: поддержка

Периодически мне попадаются учётные записи, которые содержат в имени название какой-нибудь организации, компании, продукта и т. п. Я ссылок на них не сохранял и не знаю, что с ними теперь, но вот [сегодня наткнулся на ещё одну такую учётку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282112/manticoresearch). Я считаю существование таких учёток наглой рекламой, но с другой стороны они обычно ничего плохого не делают и даже как-то кому-то там помогают в ответах по продукту, упомянутому в их имени. Но вопрос всё-таки имеется: нормально ли это? Или, может, всё учётки должны принадлежать конкретным людям (<s>[или духам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%d0%94%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)</s>) и у таких «неправильных» учёток стоит тыкать тревогу?

Comment: SmokeDetector тоже ругается в чате

Comment: Хм.. Помню, что был уже подобный вопрос, но найти не могу :(

Answer (score 3):

Почему нет, если в рамках правил сайт?

Если помогают, задают вопросы и отвечают, то почему бы и не прорекламировать в имени свой продукт, как в своём профиле, например?

А если не помогают, то их никто и не заметит.

Comment: ответ не совсем правильный. правилами сайта запрещено давать ссылки без указания аффилированности с сайтом. Тут она правда видна невооружённым глазом, да и автор прямо её упомянул в одном из двух вопросов. Так что думаю, дело ограничится беседой модераторов на тему соблюдения правил. Ответы по делу, ничего криминального нету.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr: это норма, если аккаунт и впрямь связан с заявленной организацией.**

Если не связан — то уже не факт.

---

Из сколько-нибудь близких ограничений в [соглашении](https://stackexchange.com/legal) есть лишь такой запрет:

> (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person

На "false identity" описанные случаи сколько-нибудь тянут только в случае, если аккаунт не имеет реального отношения к организации. И такой демонстративной ассоциацией с организацией без реального отношения к ней лишь **вводит в заблуждение**, а это считается злонамеренным действием и может караться.

Впрочем, если речь о почти никому не известной организации, то как вреда, так и потенциальной выгоды от такого введения в заблуждение практически нет, поэтому направленно охотиться за подобными профилями нет никакого смысла.

А "impersonate another person" неприменим, поскольку речь не о личности.

---

*Есть прецедент: лично ставил тревогу для модераторов на комментарий от имени пользователя "Stack Overflow". На мой взгляд, такое имя может вводить в заблуждение, ассоциируясь с "сотрудниками сайта". [Утверждается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6775/%D0%A3%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/6781?noredirect=1#comment26809_6781), что меры приняли (и имя вскоре действительно изменилось) и тревога полезная, хотя почему-то и отклонилась.*

Comment: Учитывая, что на enSO [таких много](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=stack+overflow), то официальная позиция, видимо, иная.

Comment: @alexolut там столько пользователей, что нет, это мало, и сколько-нибудь "отсвечивающих" там нет. Профиль, на который я оставлял тревогу, принадлежал гораздо более активному участнику, чем даже самый "верхний" из этого списка.

Comment: Собственно, [вот](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280033/3240681).

Comment: @alexolut хм? Про официальную позицию там ничего нет. Мартин тогда и модератором-то не был.

Comment: Насчет отклоненной тревоги - с участником связались, он сразу же переименовался. Не уверен, почему тревога помечена как отклоненная, скорее всего по ошибке.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за информацию :3

Comment: @PashaPash давайте там уже свежеизбранных ромбов обучите как следует.

Answer (score -1):

На сайте предусмотрен отдельный вид тревог именно для данного случая:

> **спам**
>
> Рекламирует продукт или услугу, [не раскрывая при этом причастность
>   автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Если вы сознательны, можете нажать тревогу на этих двух сообщениях. В принципе, на них действительно также [ругнулся](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42420737#42420737) и детектор спама в чате.

Модераторы доберутся до этой тревоги и проведут профилактическую беседу, если нарушение имело место быть.

Однако вы читали ответы? В них приведена ссылка на документацию, сами ответы по делу. Так что конкретно в этом случае всё достаточно нормально. Но бывают ещё множество других вариантов, например, откровенный спам или [спам по профилям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2952/213987).

Comment: То ли я не осилил понять фразу «не раскрывая при этом причастность автора», то ли я действительно не вижу причин тыкать эту тревогу — ответы всё-таки вполне нормальные, примеры есть, и ссылки на документацию в ответах по теме

Comment: В случае спама _в профиле_ надо на нормальные сообщения ставить не тревогу "Спам", а тревогу **модераторам** с описанием ситуации. Кроме того, в профилях по части контента свободы гораздо больше. То, что могут счесть спамом в сообщении, для профиля может быть совершенно нормальным.